# VS2010 Express + Silverlight - Strangest thing

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-express

Bit of a random one here, and I've exhausted my knowledge on how to try and remedy this.

Basically I've just switched out my hard-drive over to an SSD (best move I ever did), and along with this I've had to reinstall everything from the ground up. When I've done so however VS2010 Express for Windows Phone keeps giving me this error with my existing projects(Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed + bunch of warnings).

[image: Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed + bunch of warnings]

But I have made sure it is installed

[image]

I have gone through reinstalling the Silverlight 4 SDK, uninstalling all of Silverlight + VS (and all it's many, many components in Control Panel) and performed updates via Windows Update, rebooting etc. Nothing seems to work.

Strange thing is though, if I create a new project it works just fine, no warnings, no errors, nothing. I'm completely stumped.

Any ideas guys?

My usual install process is:

Silverlight SDK > VS2010 Express for WP7 > Begin Developing

I have deleted the .suo/.user files, also the obj and Bin directories too. No avail :(

The only thing really that has changed since my last install was the directory I am loading the actual projects from (but I don't see how this could affect it?).

Comment: Please write the question here on Stack Overflow instead of just providing a link to another site with the question.

Comment: Can you create a new Silverlight 4 project from scratch? If you can the easiest thing is perhaps to create a new empty project and then migrate all the source files from the old project. If you can't - then you have to fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this one without performing a full reinstall. I did discover some other elements of Win32 applications having issues as well, seems my Windows install was simply broken.